# ProgressDialog disappers after screen lock

Tags: android

I have a ProgressDialog that is running and accepting the percent complete from a thread handle.  When the screen is locked, then unlocked, the app returns back to the home screen of the app and does not continue to display the ProgressDialog.

How can I return to the same page with the ProgressDialog on it?  I assume I need to somehow save the handle resource and recreate it on onResume but am unsure how to do this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're on the right track. Assuming you have class variables showProgressDialog and myProgress:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if(showProgressDialog)
      {
        myProgressDialog.show();
        myProgressDialog.setProgress(myProgress);
      }

}
```

Comment: Is the activity recreated when the screen is locked?  If so, I wont have access to the old thread handle and therefore wont be able to receive the progress.  Thanks.

Comment: It depends. Your activity might get killed if the os needs memory. So in order to save stuff you can use http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSaveInstanceState%28android.os.Bundle%29 and http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onRestoreInstanceState%28android.os.Bundle%29

Comment: I dont believe onSave/RestoreInstanceState will work since the thread handler is an object.  Also, when the app is restored, the homepage activity is shown instead of one of the subpages with the ProgressDialog on it.  It looks like the app is just reloaded.